# Python Class. key exists as self.key, but doesn't exists in self.__dict__

Tags: python, arrays, class, oop

My class contain three big dicts, one appear in `self.__dict__` other two not.

Example:

```
class MyClass:
  big_matrix = {}
  side_array = {}
  map_of_data = {}
  def __init__( self ):
      # etc...
```

While I'm trying to dump `self.__dict__` to terminal, I successfully see only `big_matrix` and nopt other dicts.

No one array declared in `__init__`, its declared in other functions, later.

Help me please?

Comment: Can you show us `__init__`? That's what will determine _instance_ variables as opposed to the _class_ variables you've declared here.

Comment: No one array declared in `__init__`, its declared in other function, later.

Comment: have you initialised them inside the init method? There should be none in `self.__dict` if they are class attributes

Comment: `MyClass.__dict__` will have all them listed but the instances of `MyClass` will not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should initialize your variables in `__init__` and assign them to the object `self` in order to make them belong to the instance namespace (the one that is shown when invoking `__dict__` on an object.

Otherwise they are not part of your *object instance* namespace, but of the *class* namespace.

Probably you see `big_matrix` in your instance namespace because you are creating a `self.big_matrix` somewhere else in the class.

---

### Variables in instance namespace

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.big_matrix = {}
        self.side_array = {}
        self.map_of_data = {}
```

The variables belong to the instance namespace:

```
>>> print MyClass().__dict__ 
{'big_matrix': {}, 'side_array': {}, 'map_of_data': {}}
```

The class doesn't have any variable in its namespace

```
>>> print MyClass.__dict__
{}
```

---

### Variables in class namespace

```
class MyClass:
    big_matrix = {}
    side_array = {}
    map_of_data = {}
```

The instance doesn't have any *variable* in its namespace:

```
>>> print MyClass().__dict__ 
{}
```

All the variables belong to the *class* namespace (plus others used by the class):

```
>>> print MyClass.__dict__
{'big_matrix': {}, 'side_array': {}, '__module__': '__main__', 'map_of_data': {}, '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: You are right, big matrix initialized in another way than other two arrays. What is right, to declare such variables in `__init__` or as Class vars? Is it kind of error, python specific, that variables defined not correctly?

Comment: If your matrices are relative to instances then define them as instance variables. If they are class static (any object will share them) declare them as class variables.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `class attributes` and `instance attributes` is best shown with an example:

```
In [25]: class MyClass:
   ....:       cls_dict = {} # class attribute
   ....:       def __init__( self ):
   ....:               pass
   ....:           

In [26]: 

In [26]: m = MyClass() # first instance

In [27]: m.cls_dict["foo"] = "bar" # first instance adds to dict

In [28]: m1 = MyClass() # second instance 

In [29]: m1.cls_dict["bar"] = "foo" # second instance adds to dict

In [30]: MyClass.cls_dict
Out[30]: {'bar': 'foo', 'foo': 'bar'} # both entries in the dict

In [31]: m.cls_dict  # can be accessed through the class or an instance
Out[31]: {'bar': 'foo', 'foo': 'bar'}
In [32]: m1.cls_dict
Out[32]: {'bar': 'foo', 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Instance attribute:

```
In [33]: class MyClass:
   ....:    def __init__( self ):
   ....:       self.ins_dict = {}
   ....:         

In [34]: m = MyClass()

In [35]: m.ins_dict["foo"] = "bar" 

In [36]: m1 = MyClass()

In [37]: m1.ins_dict["bar"] = "foo"

In [38]: m.ins_dict   # each instance has its own `ins_dict`
Out[38]: {'foo': 'bar'}

In [39]: m1.ins_dict
Out[39]: {'bar': 'foo'}
```

`class attributes` are shared among `instances`, `instance attributes` are created for each instance separately.

Any time you change the `class attribute` `cls_dict` it will change for both instances.

Comment: What do you mean shared? will two instance has access to the same `cls_dict = {}` from your first example?

Comment: Yes. You can see from the example that any update to the class attribute dict whether by the instance or using the class to access it adds the data to the same dict. In the instance attribute dict each time you create an instance of the class, a new dict object is created for each instance.

Comment: You're welcome.  Which one you choose depends completely on what you want to use it for.